# Is there a way to bind an already running GUI application through SSH so I can see it when I access the device remotely?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, gui

After I leave work, I would like to access the windows that I have left open on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I have SSH access and can remotely start GUI applications. However, I would like to see the GUI applications that are already open. Can I do that through SSH?

Comment: You can find the Process Id of applications with `ps ax  | grep foo` command.

Comment: @Mahdi, Thank you for your response. But once I have the Pid, how can I now make myself see the GUI while I am ssh'd into my machine?

Comment: Ssh is a command-line environment, and doesn't support graphical apps. You need to connect to your machine via vnc or rep protocol.